# rails3 application uses jquery but doesn't include it in the Gemfile, should it?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, generator, gemfile

I've inherited a rails application that uses jquery
It has lots of javascript include in assets/javascripts, the application.js that requires all the other files including

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

That's good and the javascript is working ok.

However I was also expecting to see

```
gem "jquery-rails"
```

in the Gemfile.

**Question:

Is the gemfile entry only needed for initial generators like `rails g jquery:install` and is it ok to *not* include it if *not* using the generators - will the js still work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual source of `jquery` and `jquery_ujs` is included inside the gem, so you will need to keep it. However, if you're using the asset pipeline and precompile your assets, than the gem doesn't need to be loaded after the precompilation. This means that it is safe to put the gem inside your `assets` group inside your Gemfile.

If you don't have jquery-rails inside your Gemfile at all, and it does still work, that means that the source of jquery is somewhere else inside your load path. You might want to check out `app/assets`, `lib/assets` and `vendor/assets`. This is okay, but it not necessary and it means that you won't get updates automatically when doing a bundle update.

Comment: +1 Thanks iiain.  I finally found it in my Gemfile.  It was a where's Waldo moment.  However I learned a lot in the process!

Comment: If you are using jquery, then `jquery.js` (or a minimized version), should be somewhere inside your project. There are some javascript projects that include jquery inside their project, but I don't know which ones and it should be very rare.

Answer (score 1):

So long as the JQuery JS is loaded in your browser JQuery will still work.